# How to prevent Jboss from using log4j for its logging subsystem?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, log4j2

I have a web application which uses Log4j2 and I am deploying it on JbossEAP 6.0.
However I am using some libraries which still use Log4j. So for this I have added the log4j-1.2 api jar provided for log4j2. The issue I am facing is that my application is logging everything using log4j2 but the libraries are still logging using log4j.

I am guessing that this is because Jboss is adding its own copy of log4j to the classpath. Hence I tried by excluding that module by defining it to be excluded in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

However it is still not working.

Please help.Thanks.

jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I believe it could be done similar to [enable logback in JBoss](http://blog.anotheria.net/devops/enable-logback-in-jboss/)

Comment: Can you please provide your *jboss-deployment-structure.xml*?

Comment: Added the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.